# How to load all the images located in one folder into android listview dynamically..?

Tags: android

How can i load all the images located in one folder into android listview dynamically..?

Comment: Please have a look at :

[Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012

Comment: I'm referring this link https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java, they are reading images trough web, but i want to read them from specific folder or from res/drawable

Answer (score 0):

**First** Retrieve all images from a specific using the following code.

**Second** Use LazyList concept to load images. [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

**How to get all iamges from a specific folder**

```
public void searchSDCardForImage() {

        String path = null;

        String uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        String condition = uri + " like '%/GetImageFromThisDirectory/%'";
        String[] projection = { uri, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE };
        Vector additionalFiles = null;
        try {
            if (additionalFiles == null) {
                additionalFiles = new Vector<String>();
            }



            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    condition, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                boolean isDataPresent = cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (isDataPresent) {

                    do {

                        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(uri));
System.out.println("...path..."+path);
additionalFiles.add(path);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```